# Textarea height does not fit content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am working on a simple code editor application and I stumbled upon a visual bug, basically the textarea is a little bit taller than the container.

This is the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body class="page">
    <div class="files">

    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="lines">

        </div>
        <div class="editor">
            <textarea></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the index.css:

```
.lines {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #34495e;
}

.editor {
    height: 100%;
    flex: 20;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.page {
    height: 80vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    resize: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background-color: #2c3e50;
}

.files {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.file {
    
}
```

```css
.lines {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #34495e;
}

.editor {
    height: 100%;
    flex: 20;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.page {
    height: 80vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    resize: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background-color: #2c3e50;
}

.files {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.file {
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body class="page">
    <div class="files">

    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="lines">

        </div>
        <div class="editor">
            <textarea></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried everything but cannot find a solution, searched around Stackoverflow but could not find an answer I thought it was caused by the resize, border and outline, but appearently those are not the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `box-sizing: border-box;` to your textarea styles